# I entered a letter in switch case but it doesn't output what letter I've inputted

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Switch case statement doesn't work. I entered the letter which I want but it doesn't show

[image: Switch case statement doesn't work. I entered the letter which I want but it doesn't show]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without *a clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers.  You need to debug your code and create a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! Please do not post images of your code and log messages. You will much more likely receive help when you post the **actual text** of the code and logs.

Comment: Okay thank you for your concern

Answer (score 1):

There is no `switch (item1)` anywhere to be found in your code.

Comment: where should I input the switch(item1)?

Comment: After `item1` has the value it needs to have but before the first `case` that depends on that value.

Comment: Okay. i'll try what you suggested